# Is there a maven dependency for org.alfresco.repo?

Tags: maven, dependencies, alfresco, activiti

I'm trying to add a listener for a service task when creating a new business process. I've found the following example:

```java
package ru.psb.alfresco.workflow.listeners;

import org.activiti.engine.delegate.DelegateTask;
import org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener;

public  class ShowDocList extends ScriptTaskListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    org.alfresco.repo.jscript.ScriptLogger log = new org.alfresco.repo.jscript.ScriptLogger();

    @Override
    public void notify(DelegateTask arg0) {
        ...
    }

}
```

But eclipse doesn't know anything about the import `org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener;`

So what dependency do I need to add for this package? Google doesn't give me the appropriate result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener` class is contained in the following artifact:

`org.alfresco:org.alfresco-repository`.

It is not available in maven central, but instead it can be found in the following repository:
https://maven.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public/

So in your pom you would need to add the following:

```xml
<project>
    ...
    <repositories>
        ...
        <!-- define the alfresco maven repository -->
        <repository>
            <id>Alfresco Maven Repository</id>
            <url>https://maven.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
        ...
    </repositories>

    ...
    <dependencies>
        <!-- add dependency to alfresco-repository -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.alfresco</groupId>
            <artifactId>alfresco-repository</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.c</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    ...
</project>
```